# Origen del mexicanismo DEBRAYAR

Tags: origen

En México el verbo coloquial *debrayar* significa divagar o decir incoherencias. Me imagino que debe venir del francés *débraillé* que correspode a *desaliñado*. Sin embargo, esta última no se usa mucho en conversación, y la influencia francesa directamente al español de México es rara.

Así, ¿Cómo surgió *debrayar*?

Answer (score -1):

El verbo *"debrayar"* no está directamente relacionado con el francés, y es más una coincidencia. Es por eso que la influencia "francesa" no está estrechamente relacionada con este.

La palabra *"debrayar"* significa decir cosas sin sentido (incoherencias). Debido a que es un **verbo coloquial**, no se sabe a ciencia cierta su origen.

Esto es porque el lenguaje español, en sí mismo, es rico en lenguaje informal y coloquial, y comúnmente se usan varias palabras en contextos informales, que incluso pueden surgir en ese momento. Es por esto que no se sabe a ciencia cierta la historia o el origen de esta palabra.

Comment: Que una palabra sea coloquial no significa que no haya una historia clara de la misma. Si el término es demasiado nuevo es probable que no haya ningún estudio etimológico y que por eso no se sepa

Comment: Spanish is so cool!  It has a very consistent and intelligible spelling and grammar. It reminds me of Arabic where nearly every word is spelled phonetically. I often wonder if the language adopted this convention from the Moors. Most English only speakers are surprised that the concept of a Spelling Bee doesn't exist in Spanish speaking countries.